# Can I use a US B2 (visitor) visa to attend a conference?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, conferences

I have a US B2 visitor visa for 10 years. Can I use this visa to attend a week-long conference in the US? If not what type of visa do I need to apply for again?

Comment: Is that a B1/B2 or a B2?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Traveling to US for a conference as a remote worker for US company](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/178002/traveling-to-us-for-a-conference-as-a-remote-worker-for-us-company)

Comment: Are you speaking at the conference, and if so are you being paid?